# Android RecyclerView LinearSmoothScroller BUG - scrolls to end even when other index was given to scroll to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a Horizontal Recycler view vith a number list items. If an item is selected I want the Item to be centered on the scroll view.
I have created a LinearSmoothScroller the following way:

```
 smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(getContext()) {
            @Override
            protected int getHorizontalSnapPreference() {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
            }
            @Override
            protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
            }
            @Override
            public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                return layoutManager.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition); }
        };
```

Then in my method I calculate the position where to scroll to:

```
private void centerPosition(int columnIndex){
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        int visibleInterval = lastVisibleItemPosition - firstVisibleItemPosition;
        int centerOffset = visibleInterval / 2;
        int moveToIndex = columnIndex - centerOffset;

        if (moveToIndex > firstVisibleItemPosition-visibleInterval && moveToIndex < lastVisibleItemPosition) {
            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(moveToIndex);
            try {
                layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogDb.addLog(LogType.APPLICATION, "Layout scroll error");
            }
        }
    }
```

the scoll can happen on touch, or by some automatic mechanism in my app, going through the items to stepping from left to right or to right to left.

It works like 98% of the time.
Usually I have like 150-200 items in my list.

When going through the list stepping from right to left, there is one or two times, that the LinearSmoothScroller scrolls to the very end, instead of centering the list. They allways happen in the same spot.

In the debugger I have found the cases when it fails all the time:

```
columnIndex = 43
firstVisibleItemPosition = 37
lastVisibleItemPosition = 52
visibleInterval = 15
centerOffset = 7
moveTOindex = 36
```

```
columnIndex = 14
firstVisibleItemPosition = 8
lastVisibleItemPosition = 23
visibleInterval = 15
centerOffset = 7
moveTOindex = 7
```

But in case of the following example there is no problem even though it still moves 1 position to the left.

```
columnIndex = 91
firstVisibleItemPosition = 85
lastVisibleItemPosition = 100
visibleInterval = 15
centerOffset = 7
moveTOindex = 84
```

What may cause this problem for those 2 specific cases?